# Acting with a superoperator to states in qutip

Tags: qutip

I can generate a random superoperator in qutip using the command rand_super(N) $\mathcal{E}$ where I only need to inser the dimension of the superoperator is acting on, denoted as N. The same superoperator should be able to act on a state, that is a density matrix, NxN $\rho$.

Question: How can I do this using Qutip? Literally, given $\rho$ I can generate a random $\mathcal{E}$, but I couldn't find $\mathcal{E}(\rho)$.

I don't know if this is really a qutip question, maybe I could do this using simply numpy? I also tried to look up for this and qutip only teaches to find properties of the matrices and not how to perform this specific kind of operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an operator $U$ acting on a state $\rho$ as $U\rho$, it's superoperator representation $\mathcal{E}$ would act on the superket representation of the state $\rho$, which is denoted as $|\rho\rangle\rangle$. This superket is just a vector made up of the columns of $\rho$ stacked on each other:
$$
\rho = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 
c & d  \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow |\rho\rangle\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ c \\ b \\ d \end{pmatrix}.
$$
To do this in QuTiP, you have

```
import qutip as qt

N = 3
rho = qt.rand_dm(N) # Random 3x3 density matrix
rho_vec = qt.operator_to_vector(rho)
```

You can then act on this super ket with the super operator $\mathcal{E}|\rho\rangle\rangle$. Note that for the equivalent operator $U$ acting on the state $\rho$, $U\rho$ is not necessarily equal to $\rho U$. So you have to keep tabs on whether the superoperator is left- or right-multiplied. A nice explanation is given [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/163586). In QuTiP, this is handled by calling `spre(rho)`, `spost(rho)`, and `sprepost(rho, rho)`, detailed [here](https://qutip.org/docs/4.0.2/apidoc/functions.html#qutip.superoperator.spost).

Comment: Thank you for the objective and helpful answer!